# Uncheck checkbox after alert message

Tags: oracle-apex

I created dynamic action in oracle apex i.e when selecting more than one check box it displays that "to select only one checkbox" if i click ok button of this message the checkboxes should be unchecked

Comment: Why are you using checkboxes if you don't want the user to select more than one? That's what radio buttons or select list items are for.

Comment: Just started to learn oralce Apex .So creating an app and going through to all the stuffs to get knowedge

Answer (score 0):

After the confirm DA, add another DA with plsql code

```
:PXX_CHECKBOX_ITEM := null;
```

items to submit ->
:PXX_CHECKBOX_ITEM

Comment: Hi valerio costa checkbox is a column not item ,how can i set column to null

Comment: Raghu next time pls describe your problem with all the information you can :)

Comment: Valerio, please check the query for classic report with checkbox and created an DA   on this check that is when checked more than one checkboxes it displays an alert saying "you are not allowed to check more than one" .After closing this alert  box  both the checkboxes are checked.But both the checkboxes need to be unchecked after clicking ok button of alert message.  query is select EMPNO,
       apex_item.checkbox(1,EMPNO) as checkbox, 'Edit' AS EDIT,FIRST_NAME, LAST__NAME, EMAILID,SALARY, HIREDATE DOB, ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE, DESIGNATION,E.DEPARTMENT,TERMINATION_DATE from table name

Comment: Hi valerio can you help me

Answer (score 0):

What Valerio wrote would work, but I am guessing this is to do with the apex.item stuff you have been dealing with.

You will need to add another DA that is triggered by clicking the ok button. Then you need to have the DA run Javascript code. Since I saw you were asking about how to run javascript, in this case you need to go into the true actions of the dynamic action and set the Action to Execute Javascript code.(For other Javascript code you can click on Page XX: Name of page  in the Rendering tab on the left, and if you scroll down on the right there should be a section for Javascript)

And the Javscript code you need to execute to uncheck should be $s or something similair. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6341/index-en.html is a good starting point on just these basics.

I actually tend to avoid interactive reports, I prefer Interactive Grids. But you do you. If you do get into Interactive grids I recommend you go through this: https://github.com/mgoricki/orclapex-ig-cheat-sheet

Comment: nice link to github @TineO didn't knew about it thanks a lot