# Alert message from PLSQL in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I want to display an alert message from PLSQL if a certain condition is met. However it's not working.

Please check my PLSQL code which I wrote in dynamic action when clicking a checkbox.

```
declare
var_hire DATE ;
tenure_dt DATE;
i number;
TENURE EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
SELECT HIREDATE INTO var_hire from employee where empno=107;
-- APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1);
SELECT var_hire+ INTERVAL '1' YEAR INTO  tenure_dt FROM DUAL;
 IF SYSDATE < to_Date(tenure_dt,'DD-MON-YY') THEN

 /* APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR (
p_message  => 'The employee cannot be deleted',
p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );*/
apex_application.g_global_notification( 'The employee cannot be deleted');
END IF ;
END  ;

declare
var_hire DATE ;
tenure_dt DATE;
i number;
TENURE EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
SELECT HIREDATE INTO var_hire from employee where empno=107;
-- APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1);
SELECT var_hire+ INTERVAL '1' YEAR INTO  tenure_dt FROM DUAL;


    APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR (
    p_message  => 'The employee cannot be deleted',
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );
    


EXCEPTION
WHEN TENURE THEN 
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'CANNOT BE DELETED');
END  ;
```

Comment: Does `APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR` not working? Also are you sure that the `IF` is satisfying. Try keeping this outside the loop once and check

Comment: Hi Arun,its not working

Comment: Yes arun Apex_error.add_error is not working

Comment: Hi Arun my version is 19.2 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201838/discussion-between-arun-palanisamy-and-raghu).

Comment: Hi  Arun dont have access to chat

Comment: Arun can you please help out in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624306/uncheck-checkbox-after-alert-message/58624367?noredirect=1#comment103587696_58624367

Comment: Arun its not  working

Comment: Is it working now? or still issues?

Comment: Arun working on it.will get back to you

Comment: Arun .thansk a lot. perfect

Comment: Can you help me on this query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624306/uncheck-checkbox-after-alert-message/58624367?noredirect=1#comment103587696_58624367

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Ajax callback process` with your PL/SQL CODE. For example create the Ajax callback process as **MyQuery**

```
declare
var_hire DATE ;
tenure_dt DATE;
i number;
TENURE EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT HIREDATE INTO var_hire from employee where empno=107;
    SELECT var_hire+ INTERVAL '1' YEAR INTO  tenure_dt FROM DUAL;
         IF SYSDATE < to_Date(tenure_dt,'DD-MON-YY') THEN
            HTP.P('The employee cannot be deleted');    
         END IF ;
END  ;
```

And then create a Dynamic Action ('Execute javascript Code) on your check box with below `javascript code`

```
apex.server.process('MyQuery', { },
   {
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(pData) {
         if (pData != "") {
            apex.message.alert(pData);
         }
      }
  });
```

Comment: @Raghu , check the answer section here [How to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)